# How can I stop my cat from attacking my hermit crabs?

Tags: cats

So I have a very sassy kitty at home. Shes going to be 6 in June(2019). I am also the owner of hermit crabs. She has never bothered them before. But lately shes been trying to break into the cage when I am not around. I have a pin that locks the lid on the cage, and she recentlu fell through the lid which is made up of screen. After fixing it, we have to keep something covering the screen or else she tries to get ontop of the cage again. People have said to spray her with water but I want to know if there is an easier way to teach her not to break in.

Answer (score 1):

Spraying with water is usually not effective, because cats are smart enough to realize that you are the source of the water, so they just need to wait until you aren't there.

The better option is to make it so your cat cannot possibly break in. There's many ways you might go about doing this. Like, keeping the cat out of the room where the hermit crabs are kept. Or replacing the cage they're kept in with something sturdier, so the lid will support her weight. Or keeping the hermit hermit crabs up high enough that she can't jump into their cage. There's probably other things you can try too.

It's also likely the cat is behaving this way because she's bored. You should try entertaining her more, so that she won't be as inclined to bother them.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the answer. No lie. This cat does the impossible. It's like she's magician or something. Haha. She doesn't bother the cage when were home and when we leave we put items on the screen so she cant get ontop of the screen. I love her but she's something else! Thanks again!